# Complete binary search tree insertion

Tags: language-agnostic, binary-tree

I have an application that requires a data structure with the following characteristics:

- in-order traversal in O(n)
- lookup in O(log n)
- insertion in O(log n) with space O(log n) or less
- efficient in-place storage (= the tree can be modified in-place in a contiguous array with no holes)
- iterative, if possible
- deletion is not required

I found **complete** binary search trees to be a good structure for these operations. I've implemented traversal and lookup easily (they're pretty much generic) but am having a really hard time with insertion. I can't seem to insert arbitrary elements and rebalance the tree without losing either the shape property (complete tree) or the partition property (all elements on the left of a node compare strictly less than the node).

I can't find anything else online either, the only references I find are about general binary trees (with no shape property) and are not applicable in my case. Complete trees are unpopular for some reason.

Has anyone implemented insertion for complete binary trees and could give me some pointers on how to implement it robustly and efficiently? This is not homework, I need it for a real project.

Comment: plz explain 'the tree can be modified in-place in a contiguous array with no holes'. in what time? should array be sorted? can this array be considered read-only?

Comment: @piotrek As in, the tree should be storable in an array without the array having any empty slots. The tree must support insertion in O(log n) time but does not require deletion.

Comment: still don't get it. let's say the structure is self-balancing tree. it fulfil all operations are O(lg n), space is O(n), it can be sufficiently iterable. but there is no array underneath. creating such array is O(n) time and space. furthermore, any modification of such array don't influence the original structure. is it 'efficient in-place storage'?

Comment: @piotrek That doesn't work. I need my tree to be readable in-place from a file *with 100% storage efficiency*. Self-balancing trees don't offer that, because even though the tree might be balanced, it isn't complete, so there will be "gaps" when the tree is stored to a file. The tree cannot be buffered into memory. I would use a sorted array but unfortunately it has O(n) insertion as elements after the insertion point need to be shifted up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want lookup in O(log n) and insertion at arbitrary positions in O(log n), you will need a self balancing search tree. Complete binary trees cannot be updated efficiently - they are considered static data structures which are made for read-only scenarios.

Comment: Oh, wow, that would explain it, I was trying to solve an impossible problem haha. But wouldn't self-balancing trees require a sparse array for storage (or would need to be packed/unpacked somehow)? I would like to be able to do everything directly in-place from a file, without temporary storage. Is this possible?